# Logging multiple channels

Tags: logging, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to move messages from brokers.

I defined several channels in an xml file to transfer messages from a queue in a RabbitMQ X to another queue in RabbitMQ Y.

Following the configuration for one channel:

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.7.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">


    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="myChannelLog" level="warn"  logger-name="catLogChannel1" /> 

    <int:channel id="myChannel" >
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="myChannelLog" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672"  cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/>
    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelAdapter1" channel="myChannel" queue-names="myqueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  auto-startup="true"  channel-transacted="true"  />

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest" username="guest1111" password="guest" addresses="YY.YY.YY.YY:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/> 
    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest"/>
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannelAdapter1" routing-key="keyMyQueue" channel="myChannel" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" />

</beans>
```

In this sample i used the user "guest1111" on the outbound channel adapter to simulate an error on the target. If my target borker is down then i would like to know which channel have errors to restart the broker...

I would like to write in a log file all errors on channel to isolate which channel have problems (having one logfile for each channel)

Here is my log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=warn, logFileError

log4j.appender.logFileError=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFileError.File=c:/tmp/logs/logFileError.log
log4j.appender.logFileError.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.logFileError.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logFileError.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFileError.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %M%n


# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.category.catLogChannel1=warn, logFileChannel1
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1.File=c:/tmp/logs/logChannel1.log
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFileChannel1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %M%n


# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.category.catLogChannel2=warn, logFileChannel2
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2.File=c:/tmp/logs/logChannel2.log
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFileChannel2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %M%n
```

With this configuration, I have:

Stack trace is going in the logFileError.log => OK

```
2018-01-04 15:06:21 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:21 WARN  ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler:73 - handleError
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:941)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:851)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:771)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:198)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:752)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1470)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[9], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=myqueue, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=myqueue, amqp_redelivered=false, id=c08e2912-ebfe-c7c7-555a-de12694ae9a3, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-33csWFlgiMh7YB8Bud-3Og, timestamp=1515074781652}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:203)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:848)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:712)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:122)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:342)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:909)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352)
    ... 32 more
2018-01-04 15:06:21 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler:73 - handleError
```

In my specific log file I have message like:

```
2018-01-04 15:06:21 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:21 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:22 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:23 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:23 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
2018-01-04 15:06:23 WARN  catLogChannel1:197 - handleMessageInternal
```

How can I have the stacktrace also present in my specific log file instead of the message "handleMessageInternal"? Or a more explicit message on the stacktrace cause?

**Edited on 10/01/2018**

I used spring integration to manage a bridge between two brokers to transfer message from several queues (2 in this sample). This works very well, but i  In the same xml file I have declared two channels as follows:

```
<int:channel id="firstChannel" ></int:channel>
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672"  cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="firstChannel" id="inboundChannelAdapter1"  queue-names="myqueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  auto-startup="true"  channel-transacted="true" error-channel="errorChannel"   />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest" username="guestsss" password="guest" addresses="YY.YY.YY.YY:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/> 
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest"/>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="firstChannel" id="outboundChannelAdapter1" routing-key="keyMyQueue" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" return-channel="errorChannel"/>


<int:channel id="secondChannel" ></int:channel>
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory2" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672"  cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="secondChannel" id="inboundChannelAdapter2"  queue-names="myqueue2" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  auto-startup="true"  channel-transacted="true" error-channel="errorChannel2" />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest2" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="YY.YY.YY.YY:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/> 
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest2" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest2"/>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="secondChannel" id="outboundChannelAdapter2" routing-key="keyMyQueue" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest2" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" />
```

I will used wire-tap later to debug messages on both channel, having messages logged on a separate log file per channel.

First I would like to log problems of the channel in separate log files.

How can I catch exception thrown by each channel? If an error occurs on the outbound channel (bad auth, queue deleted....) or on the inbound on the channel "secondChannel" i would like to trace error in a log dedicated for the specific channel (secondChannel.log)?

For this sample, I would like to have:
- firstChannel.log
- secondChannel.log
...

Is this function possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear; it's better to show the whole log message rather than truncating it like that.

If you just want to log the cause, use `expression="payload.cause"` instead of `log-full-message="false"`.

**EDIT**

This does exactly what I would expect...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd">

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="one" error-channel="error1" queue-names="one" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="one" expression="1 / 0" />

    <int:channel id="error1" />
    <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="error1" logger-name="log1" />

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="two" error-channel="error2" queue-names="two" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="two" expression="1 / 0" />

    <int:channel id="error2" />
    <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="error2" logger-name="log2" />

</beans>
```

Errors on channel `one` go to `log1` and errors on `two` go to `log2`.

testLog1.log:

```
09:52:47.900 [(inner bean)#b7838a9-1] INFO  log1 - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: 1 / 0; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[6], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=one, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=one, amqp_redelivered=false, id=b659ac0e-0d7f-63d6-4081-331d4d9df423, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-CWkI-XVj4vKupHWSGjWtgA, timestamp=1516287167896}]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

and the same thing in testLog2.log

This test used logback, but the logging framework will make no difference.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile1.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile2.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

  <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
  <logger name="org.springframework.integration" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="org.springframework.amqp" level="WARN" />

  <logger name="log1" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="log2" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE2" />
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, I suggest you start a new question, with much more clarity, together with a complete working example that exhibits the problem you are trying to solve.